# Wordpress autopoulate menu with woocommerce categories

Tags: php, wordpress, drop-down-menu, woocommerce, code-snippets

I need to autopopulate my main navigarion menu with not empty woocommerce categories
`$non_empty_categories = get_categories(array('taxonomy' => 'product_cat'));`

I have maximally 2-deep subcategories under each category.

I am using Max Mega Menu plugin for this ([Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tNgz4.png)) and I just need to automatically populate this menu, [manualy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/azXz3.png) is just too much work for future (categories will change often).

Code snippet, or working plugin should be the best for this.

PS: JS Submenu plugin did NOT worked for me.

Thanks for helping me